# What is the probability that orthocentre lies inside the circumcircle

Tags: probability, geometry

If a triangle is chosen at random inscribed in a fixed circle and what is the probability that the orthocentre lies inside circumcircle?
I thought that if the triangle is acute then only the orthocentre will lie inside the circumcircle. And so thought that answer is 1/2 but answer given at back is 1/9.
Can anyone suggest how to get to right answer and what was wrong in my thinking.

Comment: As you didn't write any explanation of how you got your answer, I can only assume the only simple one that comes to my mind:  you thought that there are 2 possible outcomes - inside or outside (or maybe acute/obtuse) being smart enough to realize the probability of the point being on the circle (the triangle to be right) is equal to 0 and therefore the answer is 1/2. However these outcomes have different probabilities, so the answer is not 1/2. It's like the probability of meeting a dinosaur on the street nowadays is not 1/2 even though you either meet it or not.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think $\frac{1}{9}$ is the right answer unless I have understood the problem wrong.

If you randomly select 3 points A, B and C on the circumference, it is easy to see that the probability of one of the angles being obtuse is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. It requires only one angle out of the three to be obtuse.

What is the probability of $\angle A$ being obtuse? Say, you take point C and draw a line through the circumcenter. For $\angle A$ to be obtuse, point A has to be on the same side of the semi-circle as B.

i) The probability of both A and B being on the same side = $\frac{1}{2}$
ii) The probability of A being between B and C, rather than B being in between C and A = $\frac{1}{2}$

So, the probability of $\angle A$ being obtuse = $\frac{1}{4}$

For any of the 3 angles being obtuse, the probability will be $\frac{3}{4}$.

So, the probability of the triangle being acute = $\frac{1}{4}$

The answer should be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: There are three types of triangles with regard to the angles: acute, right, and obtuse. The orthocenter will always be **inside** of an acute triangle, it is **on** a right triangle, and it will be **outside** of an obtuse triangle.

Comment: bro i got till there but using that answer is 1/2 and not 1/9

Comment: Formula for the probability of $A$ and $B$ (independent events): $p(A \operatorname{and} B) = p(A) * p(B)$.